# Does OpenAL have an equivalent to WebAudioContext.currentTime?

Tags: openal

In the Web Audio API, there is a [`currentTime` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/currentTime) which can be used to track time as understood by the audio system.  This means that, for example, if you're playing an hours-long song, you can keep graphics in perfect sync with it even if the audio clock is significantly faster or slower than the system's real-time clock.

Does OpenAL have an equivalent to this?  I cannot find one in the [specification](https://www.openal.org/documentation/openal-1.1-specification.pdf).

Comment: It's been a long time since I last worked with OpenAL but: no, I don't recall such a feature. I can't give a definitive answer, though.